# Tagmail-how to setup our smtp server in master

Tags: puppet

```
I need to use my own smtp server instead of puppet default tagmail for sending reports.The given procedure in puppet Doc is not working 

[transport]
reportfrom = reports@example.org
smtpserver = smtp.example.org    //Gave my smtp server name
smtpport = 25
smtphelo = example.org 

[tagmap]`enter code here
all: myemail@gmail.com
webserver, !mailserver: httpadmins@example.com, you@example.com
```

what needs to be added further and is there any missing configurations?

Comment: Which version of Puppet are you using?  And are you using the [puppetlabs::tagmail](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/tagmail) module (which version?), or the built-in tagmail of older Puppet?

Comment: @John Bollinger we  use puppet version 5.5.2 and we are using tagmail module